# Running mobile app fails, still with device connected - runOnAllDevices

Tags: android, react-native, build

I was running the project daily with that working well. I don't know what happened that now the app always fails to build with follow error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
> Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

    at makeError (/var/www/html/vituzzo_mobile/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /var/www/html/vituzzo_mobile/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/var/www/html/vituzzo_mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (/var/www/html/vituzzo_mobile/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:111:9)
```

When I run `adb devices`, it shows:

[image]

The above error used to happen when the device have disconnected.

I saw the enviroment variables and it's aparently okay:

[image]

But when I run `npx react-native doctor`, it shows that android sdk, jdk and android studio are not configured:

[image]

I tested the two options "e" and "f" from doctor, but neither was able to solve the problem

What can I do to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem! I've deleted `node_modules` folder and run `npm i`

Then, I've opened Android studio to run the app from it. After, I've run the app from Android studio with success!

I've tried to run it from the old way from terminal `npm run android` and it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Mine was even showing that:

```
    Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android   
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 29.0.3
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   2
Warnings: 0 
Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.
```

Just click on 'e' or 'f'. It took its time and installed the said missing programs (note that I already installed Android studio and all the SDK instructions on react-native docs before now but for some reason, it was not being detected)

When I ran npx react-native doctor, the issue was resolved:

Comment: Unfortunatelly when i pressed f or e it didn't work. It failed.